# Center div and keep its length as wide as the text inside without setting a width to it

Tags: css

How can I center the div headline and keep it's length as wide as the text inside (My title) without setting a width for .headline.

```
<div class="sidebar">

    <div class="headline"><p>My title</p></div>

</div>
```

Right now I am using this css, but "my title" is generated by php and differs in length:

```
.headline {
    width: 5em;
    background: #900;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: solid 1px #555;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sidebar {
  text-align: center;
}
.headline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
.sidebar{
 text-align:center;
}
.headline {
    background: #900;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: solid 1px #555;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /*For IE7*/
    *zoom:1; /*For IE7*/
}
```